# How to share a virtual environment with pipenv?

Tags: python, pipenv

Pipenv virtual environnements (*venv*) will be shared with children folders.
So for example if you have installed an *venv* in `~/foo/`, it will be accessible in `~/foo/baz/`

But what if you want to share the same *venv* between `~/foo/bob/` and `~/baz/alice/` ?

The following kind of worked for me.  I hope it can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a undocumented feature in `pipenv`: if you create a file named `.venv` in the project root with a path to a virtualenv, `pipenv` will use that instead of an autogenerated path.

(You'll still need to keep `Pipfile`'s and `Pipfile.lock`s synchronized. Making them symlinks as @MalikKoné suggests may do, but not if `Pipfile`s are under version control as they are supposed to.)

This, however, [is more fit for cases when you already have an established set of environments that you wish to reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55892572/keeping-the-same-shared-virtualenvs-when-switching-from-pyenv-virtualenv-to-pip/55893055#55893055). Otherwise, placing environments in arbitrary places is prone to create a mess eventually.

Answer (score 1):

To share virutal env with pipenv
Create a directory ~/foo/bob/

```
mkdir -p ~/foo/bob/ ; cd ~/foo/bob/
```

create a virtual env in ~/foo/bob/

```
pipenv --three
```

This will create `~/.local/share/virtualenvs/bob-signature/`

Install whatever packages you need.  For example

```
pipenv install jupyter
```

This will create a Pipfile.lock in `~/foo/bob/`

Create another directory, say `~/baz/alice/` and create a  *venv* there

```
mkdir -p ~/baz/alice ; cd ~/baz/alice/ ;  pipenv --three
```

As before pipenv will have created `alice-signature/` in `~/.local/share/virtualenvs/`.
Remove that folder and replace it by a link to *bob-signature*

```
cd ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/
rm -r alice-signature/
ln -s bob-signature/ alice-signature
```

In `~/baz/alice/`, link *Pipfile* and *Pipfile.lock* to the ones in `~/baz/bob/`

```
cd ~/baz/alice/ ;
rm Pipfile ; rm Pipfile.lock
ln -s ~/foo/bob/Pipfile . ;  ln -s ~/foo/bob/Pipfile.lock  .
```

Now, You should  have a *venv* accessible from *alice/* or *bob/*, and packages installed from any of those directories will be shared.

Comment: Symlinking won't do if `Pipfile`s are under version control (as they are supposed to).