# pipenv install django without re-downloading it every time?

Tags: python, django, command-line, pipenv

i have limited internet access temporarily, and every time i need to start a new django project i have to re-download django (and other dependencies) that i have already downloaded from other projects. is there an easier way to `pipenv install django` and other dependencies without downloading them over again every time?

i read that there is a cache of these dependencies, but if thats true my issue then becomes, i dont know how to access the cache so that the dependencies install correctly into the project. or if there was one location in my 'downloads' folder where i could install directly from it, instead of from the internet.

im hoping for something along the lines of:
`pipenv install django==2.2.0 from=c:\downloads\dependencies`

i expect that i will then install from previously downloaded files without the use of an internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can enable the pip cache via the pip config file ([pip config file user guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#config-file)):

```
[global]
no-cache-dir = false
download-cache=/path/to/cache-dir (could be /usr/local/pip/cache)
```

(don't forget to actually create the this directory)

the file's locations:

```
$HOME/.pip/pip.conf on Unix   
%HOME%\pip\pip.ini on Windows .
```

or for virtualenvs:

```
$VIRTUAL_ENV/pip.conf on Unix
%VIRTUAL_ENV%\pip.ini on Windows
```

you can create the file if its not there

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shared pipenv, which includes packages: django, djangorestframework, psycopg2 etc, to be used among your django projects. You can find an answer for how to create a shared pipenv from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48772979/4665915).